# Undefined CommonName in certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, soapui

So far, I've been working with a certificate which I added to a SoapUI 5.2 project and which gave me access to a pre-production server. However, now that I'm ready to move to a production environment, I'm trying to check the new production certificate with SoapUI, but I'm getting the next error:

```
WARN:Using fallback method to load keystore/truststore due to: Invalid keystore format
ERROR:An error occurred [java.lang.NullPointerException], see error log for details
```

And the error log says:

```
ERROR:Could not load keystore/truststore
ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.build(KeyStoreBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.build(KeyStoreBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.build(KeyStoreBuilder.java:88)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.crypto.KeyMaterialWssCrypto.fallbackLoad(KeyMaterialWssCrypto.java:206)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.crypto.KeyMaterialWssCrypto.load(KeyMaterialWssCrypto.java:168)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.crypto.KeyMaterialWssCrypto.getStatus(KeyMaterialWssCrypto.java:216)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.project.WSSTabPanel$CryptoTableModel.getValueAt(WSSTabPanel.java:643)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
...
```

The only difference I found between the pre-production and production certificates was that the latter did not have the CommonName field defined.

I know that field is not mandatory, so how is that possible? How can I solve this problem without asking for a new certificate? That's not an option.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check the `pom.xml` of SOAPUI project for [5.2 versión](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/next/soapui/pom.xml), and it use not-yet-commons-ssl versión 0.3.11:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-ssl</groupId>
        <artifactId>not-yet-commons-ssl</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

And If you check the `build` method for [`org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder`](http://juliusdavies.ca/svn/not-yet-commons-ssl/tags/commons-ssl-0.3.11/src/java/org/apache/commons/ssl/KeyStoreBuilder.java) class as the exception thrown in your error log you'll see:

```
public static KeyStore build(byte[] jksOrCerts, byte[] privateKey,
                             char[] jksPassword, char[] keyPassword)
    throws IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException,
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
    NoSuchProviderException, ProbablyBadPasswordException,
    UnrecoverableKeyException {

    ...
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, jksPassword);
        Iterator keysIt = keys.iterator();
        Iterator chainsIt = chains.iterator();
        int i = 1;
        while (keysIt.hasNext() && chainsIt.hasNext()) {
            Key key = (Key) keysIt.next();
            Certificate[] c = (Certificate[]) chainsIt.next();
            X509Certificate theOne = buildChain(key, c);
            String alias = "alias_" + i++;
            // The theOne is not null, then our chain was probably altered.
            // Need to trim out the newly introduced null entries at the end of
            // our chain.
            if (theOne != null) {
                c = Certificates.trimChain(c);
                alias = Certificates.getCN(theOne);
/* line 176 */  alias = alias.replace(' ', '_');
            }
            ks.setKeyEntry(alias, key, keyPassword, c);
        }
        return ks;
    }
}
```

So seems that you're right and the problem is that your certificate has no common name, so `org.apache.commons.ssl.Certificates.getCN(X509Certificate)` returns `null` as alias and then `alias.replace` is throwing the `NPE`.

```
                alias = Certificates.getCN(theOne);
/* line 176 */  alias = alias.replace(' ', '_');
```

I don't see nothing that says that `Common Name` is mandatory in [RFC5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), however various code/software use it for different purposes as not-yet-commons-ssl does.

Your certificate is probably right but you can't use it with `SOAPUI 5.2` version to test your environment if it hasn't the CN, so if you want to use SOAPUI to test your environment I think that you've to reissue the certificate generating a CSR with CN. Or you can report the problem to `http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/` and then ask to SOAPUI to include the latest version...

Hope this helps,

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. I already suspected the problem was in the code of the library not-yet-commons-ssl, but I hoped there would be some kind of solution I was  able to do for myself.
You did a great analysis job. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Julio nice to help you. However I only do the analysis for the reason of the error, but I'm not totally sure if there is a possible workaround, good luck finding an affordable the solution `:)`